# Groupby and comparing within group two timestamps on separate rows

Tags: python, pandas

I need to group by application_id. Then, compare two timestamps within the group in separate rows and create a boolean series "user_rejects". User_rejects should indicate if rejected_time == selected_time (on any other row within the group).

The dataset has millions of rows and more than 100 variables, and applications_ids have 15-25 rows each, so efficiency is a factor.

Example data

| application_id | id | creation_timestamp | selected_time | rejected_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 69c0 | 7 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 2023-11-21 08:30:20.881008 |
| 69c0 | 15 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-20 05:32:26.691008 |
| 69c0 | 14 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-04 05:32:26.691008 |
| 69c0 | 9 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-20 05:32:26.691010 |
| 69c0 | 18 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-20 05:32:26.691011 |
| 69c0 | 6 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 2023-11-21 08:30:20.881008 | NaT |
| 69c0 | 19 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-11 05:32:26.691008 |
| db26 | 11 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 |  | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 |
| db26 | 12 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 |  | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 |

Expected output

| application_id | id | creation_timestamp | selected_time | rejected_time | user_rejects |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 69c0 | 7 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 2023-11-21 08:30:20.881008 | 1 |
| 69c0 | 15 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-20 05:32:26.691008 | 0 |
| 69c0 | 14 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-04 05:32:26.691008 | 0 |
| 69c0 | 9 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-20 05:32:26.691010 | 0 |
| 69c0 | 18 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-20 05:32:26.691011 | 0 |
| 69c0 | 6 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 2023-11-21 08:30:20.881008 | NaT | 0 |
| 69c0 | 19 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | NaT | 2023-12-11 05:32:26.691008 | 0 |
| db26 | 11 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 |  | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 | 0 |
| db26 | 12 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 |  | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 | 0 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert columns to datetimes in first step and then compare by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in lambda function per groups:

```
cols = ['selected_time','rejected_time']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')

f = lambda x: x['rejected_time'].isin(x['selected_time'].dropna())
df['user_rejects'] = df.groupby('application_id', group_keys=False).apply(f).astype(int)
```